# Can't compile ES7 features with Webpack and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to compile my React app with support for ES7 decorators as I'm using the autobind-decorator but webpack says there is an "Unexpected token" with the router, which is the entry file for the app. I've tried various versions of babel related npms, using the the "state-0" and "transform-runtime" and they all result in the same error. Anyone's help would be very much appreciated :)

**main.js** 
[image]
**webpack.config** 
[image]
**package.json** 
[image]

Comment: To whoever down-voted my question. Could you possibly enlighten me as to why you did so, so I don't make the same mistake in future. I don't mind being down-voted but it would be good to know why. I have a feeling it might be the screen shots rather than using the markdown. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the README of babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#usage), your should use `query` field in your config, like so:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: // ....
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: [/*presets list*/],
        plugins: [/*plugins list*/]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is incorrect loader config inside your `webpack.config.js` file. You need to supply the `presets` under the `query` field in the loader config:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-1']
    }
  }
]
```